# How to compute projective probabilities of a given measurement outcome using Stim?

Tags: measurement, random-quantum-circuit, stim, qutip

I am looking to calculate the projective probabilities for each measurement outcome in a Clifford circuit and then output its corresponding tableau state. I am performing the measurement in the Z basis. The measurements should not be implementing postselections.

I have a similar code in QuTiP which gives a statevector after a projective measurement instead of Tableau representation.

```
for statename in [ '+x', '+z'] :
  print('For an initial state',statename,':')
  psi = states[statename]
  M = measurement.measurement_statistics(psi,sigmaz())
  for i in range(3) :
    print('M[%d] = ' % i)
    print(M[i])
  print()
```

```
For an initial state +x :
M[0] = 
[-1.  1.]
M[1] = 
[Quantum object: dims = [[2], [1]], shape = (2, 1), type = ket
 Qobj data =
 [[ 0.]
  [-1.]]
 Quantum object: dims = [[2], [1]], shape = (2, 1), type = ket
 Qobj data =
 [[-1.]
  [ 0.]]                                                      ]
M[2] = 
[0.4999999999999998, 0.5000000000000001]

For an initial state +z :
M[0] = 
[-1.  1.]
M[1] = 
[Quantum object: dims = [[2], [1]], shape = (2, 1), type = ket
 Qobj data =
 [[ 0.]
  [-1.]]
 Quantum object: dims = [[2], [1]], shape = (2, 1), type = ket
 Qobj data =
 [[-1.]
  [ 0.]]                                                      ]
M[2] = 
[0, 1.0]
```

Here M[2] gives the measurement probabilities of each outcome and M[1] states the corresponding statevectors. I want to obtain a Tableau state after performing a measurement and its corresponding probabilities. It may not list all the possible measurement outcome but instead only its output Tableau state and the corresponding probability. No noise, reset or postselection like situation are considered here.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How complicated are these circuits? Do the measurements all happen in one layer, or are they spread throughout? Can the circuit contain noise channels whose effects you want to affect the probabilities? Are there mid-circuit resets?

Comment: @CraigGidney , I am trying to simulate the random Clifford circuit with measurement taking place on single qubits in each layer with probability p. No, there is no reset or noise channels which has any affect on the probabilities.

Comment: Is the probability of previous measurements being different supposed to be accounted for in the expectation, or is it assumed they are fixed when computing the probability?

Comment: @CraigGidney No I am not taking into account the classical probability p. I just want to obtain the simple quantum projective probabilities of any given quantum state. In here all the quantities are fixed.  Sorry if I am not so clear. I think my objective is very simple. I just want to perform a quantum measurement on a given qubit state and then obtain its outcome i.e. both the output statevector and the probability with which I can obtain it for a single realization. I don't want to perform any statistics on them. All of this happens in a single realization.

Comment: I believe you that your case is simple, but it's important *how* it's simple for what will work and what won't. Perhaps the easiest way to make this clear is to include an example circuit and an example expected output.

Comment: For the circuit reference, please see fig1(b) of the article, https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.14280 and the projective probabilities of a measurement is defined in section 2.4 of the same paper.

Comment: @CraigGidney Thanks for your reply. Fig 1 and equation 4 of the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.08092 has probably more clear description of the quantum circuit and the example expected output respectively. I know how to perform it by converting the Tableau to a statevector in Stim.  But that method is costly. That's why I am looking for a Tableau alternative where I don't have to jump to the statevector representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the *extremely useful* properties of the subset of stabilizer circuits supported by Stim (circuits with no Clifford feedback or doubly-controlled Pauli feedback) is that, no matter what happens throughout the circuit, no matter what noise or resets or measurement results, **the final stabilizer tableau is always the same up to sign**.

If you sample the final state of a stim Circuit twice, getting state $|A\rangle$ and state $|B\rangle$, it will be the case that there exists some tensor product of Pauli operations $P$ such that $P|A\rangle = |B\rangle$. So once you know any one possible output state, you can switch your focus to "relative to this state, what different values of $P$ might I sample from this circuit?".

There are two sources of these $P$ flippers. Explicit noise channels and Heisenberg uncertainty. An explicit channel would be like `X_ERROR(0.1) 5` or `DEPOLARIZE(0.2) 6`. Heisenberg uncertainty is the fact that operations like `M 55` should be thought of as being followed by fully randomizing the commuting Pauli, so `M 55` is intrinsically followed by `Z_ERROR(0.5) 55`. In a circuit without noise, all the $P$ values you see in the final state are from different combinations of these `Z_ERROR(0.5)` terms propagating to the end of the circuit.

So, one viable strategy is to identify all of these Heisenberg uncertainties and translate them from the time they apply to the time at the end of the circuit, where they correspond to 50/50 Pauli flips of the result. You then perform Gaussian elimination to remove the redundant ones, get a set of $m$ generators $P_0$, $P_1$, ..., $P_{m-1}$ with the property that the final state is always of the form $P_0^{b_0} \ldots {P_{m-1}}^{b_{m-1}} |A\rangle$ where each $b_k$. In fact, if there's no explicit noise in the circuit, then picking the value of each $b_k$ uniformly at random this is the same as sampling from the circuit.

An alternative strategy, for noiseless circuits, is to use the fact that you know the solution looks like $P_0^{b_0} \ldots {P_{m-1}}^{b_{m-1}} |A\rangle$ with uniformly random $b_k$ and just back-infer the generators from a lot of samples. If, given a $|B\rangle$ that happens to equal some $P$ times $|A\rangle$, you can figure out the value of $P$, then you are basically set. Sample the circuit, and convert that sample into a sampled flipper $P_s$. Check if $P_s$ is a product of your existing flipper generators or not. If it is a product, discard it. If it isn't, add it as a new generator. Repeat this process until you haven't seen a new product for 40 straight attempts. There is now a less than one in a trillion chance that your current set of generators is missing a generator present in the circuit.

Comment: Can we simply create n-qubit random stabilizer product state using stim? I am currently constructing these states by uniformly sampling from the tableau corresponding to six single qubit stabilizer states (+X, -X, +Z, -Z, +Y, -Y) and then adding the tableau block diagonally for each qubit to get the n-qubit random product tableau. Does this method seems correct? or is their any other simple/fast way in which we can uniformly  sample n-qubit stabilizer product state?

Comment: @user21113 What you want is more along the lines of how often a frame simulator crashes an X error into the measurement, but with reset gates and measurement gates not producing 50/50 random Z errors to enforce Heisenberg uncertainty. Alas stim doesn't expose its frame simulator to the python API yet.